# Set DataTemplate to Attributes in Xml Binding

Tags: xml, wpf, datatemplate

I need to build a form to edit XML node attributes.
Unfortunately I don't know the number and the names of the attributes.

Suppose I wanto to edit the attributes of the first node MYNODE:

```
<MYROOT>
   <MYPARENTNODE1 Name = MyName1>
      <MYNODE Attr1 = Val1 Attr2 = Val2 ... Attr_N = Val_N />
   </MYPARENTNODE1>

   <MYPARENTNODE2 Name = MyName2>
      <MYNODE Attr1 = Val1 Attr2 = Val2 ... Attr_M = Val_M />
   </MYPARENTNODE2>

</MYROOT>
```

First I select the node attributes:

```
<XmlDataProvider 
  x:Key="dataprovider" Source="myfile.xml"  
  XPath="/MYROOT/MYPARENTNODE[@Name='MyName1']/MYNODE/@*"
 />
```

Now, if I bind this to a listbox, I get all the attribute values as the list items. What I need is to apply a datatemplate to them so that I can have LABEL-EDITCONTROL couple for each attribute in order to edit it.

Something like:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{ ??? }">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" />
        </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Really I can't find any useful example both on Microsoft or Google!

Thans for any help,
Simone

Answer (score 0):

If you need the same DataTemplate for all attributes, it is not necessary to specify DataType.